# Open a screen session inside a certain user on boot Ubuntu Server Linux

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gnu-screen

I currently have a private server which I test my web apps on which runs Ubuntu Server 10.04 I also host a few game servers (rather than having wasted CPU time :-D) for some of my friends.

These game servers I run in the game user account and each one has it's own screen session (so friends can ssh in and reboot the game server etc...). For example screen -R l4d2 runs ./start in the L4D2 folder.

However if I reboot the server (which I have to do occasionally) all these sessions close and I have to manually create all the screen sessions and run the required games within them.

Is there a way to set these screen sessions as Daemons or services or just boot on server start so they restart themselves on server reboot?

I hope I have made my question easy to understand but feel free to ask questions!

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the screen manpage

```
 -d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but
           doesn't  attach  to  it.  This  is  useful  for  system startup
           scripts.
```

I'd probably be tempted to put something in /etc/rc.local which looked a bit like

```
su - <gameuser> -c "screen -d -m /var/games/l4d2/run_the_server"
```

Comment: As far as I know, unused arguments to screen isn't treated as a program to run, so: su -c 'screen -d -m /var/games/l4d2/run_the_server' - <gameuser>

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I'm sure i had those to begin with..